# Href scroll to page with offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How can I make the page scroll to my id 
I am using the code below to make the pages croll to where I want it, but it only is triggered on page load

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - 64
}, 'slow');
```

On the links that are clickable, only

```
 href="page#a"
```

is used. This scrolls to the div but not to where I desire. Is there a way where I can also offset by 64pixels on href? Thanks

The id's css are as follows:

```
#a, #b {
    margin-bottom: 64 px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}
```

Comment: Please post your html

Comment: @LGSon i use a div for the ID that is called for the hash string on href..     <div id="a"></div> This is inserted before the table and <div id="b"> </div> is inserted before the charts section

Answer (score 1):

```
       var top_val = $('.test');
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: top_val.offset().top
        }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      function scroll (id) {
        $(id).bind('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $anchor = $(this).attr('href');
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: ($anchor).offset().top - 64
            }, 'slow');
        });
      }
      scroll('#page1');
      scroll('#page2');
    });    
    <a href="" id="page1" >Visit W3Schools</a>
    <a href="" id="page2" >Visit W3Schools</a>
```

Comment: Hi, the anchor that does href="#a" is also visible on other pages, it is on my sidebar. So i need it to link to the page too if it isnt the current page.. How would this work for 2 diff IDs btw? Thanks!

Comment: look at at the fresh answer